# PowerShell term not recognized

Tags: java, windows, powershell, cmd

I added a `JAVA_HOME` environment variable and added an entry to the `PATH` in Windows 10 so I could run Bamboo Server on my machine . In PowerShell I can not use `java -version` I get an error , but the same command works fine in CMD .

error message in PowerShell

```
java : The term 'java' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ java
...
```

the variables

```
JAVA_HOME="C:\PROGRA~2\Java\jdk1.8.0_211"
PATH=...%JAVA_HOME%\bin
```

Answer (score 1):

For this to work with PowerShell remove the double-quotes in the `JAVA_HOME` variable .

working variables

```
JAVA_HOME=C:\PROGRA~2\Java\jdk1.8.0_211
PATH=...%JAVA_HOME%\bin
```

Comment: The reason is that `"` is not a valid path character. (As an aside, it would be recommended to spell out the entire directory name, as in `JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0.211` rather than the short `PROGRA~2` name.)